# Add a specific color to each tile and a legend in geom_tile

Tags: r, geom-tile

I want to add two things to the following figure:

1. add a legend (*zp* or *df$legend*) (which is similar to each block) to the geom_tile figure
2. assign a specific color to each tile (which repeats for every block) instead of *scale_fill_continuous* but keep the "white" color for *NA* values.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(RColorBrewer)
        
    xp <- c('Disease_1','Disease_2','Disease_3','Disease_4')
    yp <- c('B Cell','T Cell')
    zp <- c('feature1','feature2','feature3','feature4','feature5','feature6','feature7','feature8')
    xp1 <- xp[1:2]
    df <- list(x=1:2,y=1:4,xp1,yp)
    df <- expand.grid(df)
    df$z <- c(1.804344554,1.158037086,1.686173307,0.500280283,1.710806067,0.857513435,0.66474755,1.164780941,1.769090931,2.058400169,3.114233859,1.436684123,1.770306398,0.995507604,2.538556363,2.264486118,1.424789875,1.816608927,2.773082903,1.197434618,0.829416784,1.622892741,2.035117094,1.650363345,1.927235048,1.546477438,2.308773122,1.041881013,1.216029616,0.478353441,0.834348006,1.240448774)
    df$legend <- rep(c('feature1','feature2','feature3','feature4','feature5','feature6','feature7','feature8'))

    cols <- rev(brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'))
    p <- ggplot(df)
    p <- p + geom_tile(aes(x, y, fill = ifelse(z > 1, z, NA)), 
                       colour = "black", width=0.85, height=0.85, size=1) + 
      scale_fill_continuous(name = "z Scale", na.value = 'white') +
      labs() +
      facet_grid(Var3~Var4) + 
      theme(strip.background =element_blank(), #remove bg color of facet_grid texts
            strip.text.x = element_text(size=12, color="black", face="bold"),
            strip.text.y = element_text(size=10, color="black", face="bold"))
    print(p)
    p + coord_fixed() +
      theme(
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For coloring, do you mean `fill=` (inside of the tiles) or `colour=` (border)? Either way, add one or both inside the `aes(.)` of `geom_tile`, potentially removing `colour="black"`. They should be based on a variable found in the data (or an expression).

Comment: FYI, `?geom_tile` includes examples that use `aes(fill=..)`, a small demonstration of how to start.